Max retry exceeded when using DeltaTable with Azure Blob Storage
I'm facing an issue when using the deltalake lib to save / loading data to Azure Blob Storage. Sometimes,  I'm getting the following error:
DatasetError: Failed while saving data to data set CustomDeltaTableDataset(file_example).
Failed to parse parquet: Parquet error: AsyncChunkReader::get_bytes error:
Generic MicrosoftAzure error: Error after 10 retries in 2.196683949s, max_retries:10, 
retry_timeout:180s, source:error sending request for url 
(https://<address>/file.parquet):
 error trying to connect: dns error: failed to lookup address information: Name or service not known

Here is an example of the parameters I'm using:
from deltalake import DeltaTable


datalake_vale = {
    'account_name': <account>,
    'client_id': <cli_id>,
    'tenant_id': <tenant_id>,
    'client_secret': <secret>,
    'timeout': '100000s'
}

# Load data from the delta table
dt = DeltaTable("abfs://<azure_address>", storage_options=datalake_vale)

I was looking for a parameter like max_retries but couldn't find anything related. Does anyone know a solution or workaround for this issue?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Failed to parse parquet  this looks like the main error.

I don't know, I'm still a bit suspicious because it's a sporadic error in such a way that I can run the same piece of code again and it completes the operation. My suspicion is related to some connection instability. It would be interesting to have a property that increases this maximum number of retries, but I couldn't find it.

you can control the number of retries and timeouts as shown below:
datalake_vale = {
    'account_name': account_name,
    'client_id': client_id,
    'tenant_id': tenant_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'timeout': '100000s',
    'retries': '20', 
    'retry_delay': '2',
}

Here is the complete code for your reference:
from deltalake import DeltaTable
import fsspec

# Azure Blob Storage configuration
account_name = '<accountName>'
client_id = '<clientId>'
tenant_id = '<tenantId>'
client_secret = '<ClientSecret>'
container_name = '<containerName>'

# Construct storage_options dictionary with retry settings
datalake_vale = {
    'account_name': account_name,
    'client_id': client_id,
    'tenant_id': tenant_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'timeout': '100000s',
    'retries': '20', 
    'retry_delay': '2',
}

# Azure Blob Storage path for Delta Table
delta_table_path = f"abfss://{container_name}@{account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/<deltaTablePath>"

# Load DeltaTable with storage_options
dt = DeltaTable(delta_table_path, storage_options=datalake_vale)

# Example: Retrieve and print schema
print(dt.schema())

You can get the output as shown below:

The delta table will load successfully and you can be able to update it. Make sure you are using ADLS account. It won't work for blob storage.

Excellent! Can you add any references to the document where you extract the information? I would like to know more about possibilities and possible units for "retry_delay" such as seconds, milliseconds and so on...

Check this MS document once.

@NaveenSharma I'm interested in the list of parameters because storage_options is not checked completely, I could put "'test': 'it's a test'" inside storage options and I would still have a table recovered. So being a sporadic error and not having a list of possible configurations makes it difficult to validate whether the solution is correct... I couldn't find a reference for retries in that link :-(
